# Where am I wrong in the following problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

We have: $f:R\rightarrow R,\:\:f\left(t\right)=At^2-2Bt+C,\:where\:A=\int _1^2\:\frac{1}{x^2}dx,\:B=\int _1^2\:\frac{e^x}{x}dx,\:C=\int _1^2\:e^{2x}dx$ and we need to show that $f\left(2B+t\right)=f\left(2B-t\right)$.
First I find A and after I wrote main function in another form: $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2}t^2-2Bt+C=\frac{1}{2}t\left(t-4B\right)+C$.

---

Okay, after this step I replaced values and I obtained something like:  $f\left(2B+t\right)=f\left(2B-t\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(t^2-4B^2\right)+C$.

But the correct answer in my book is: $f\left(2B+t\right)=f\left(2B-t\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(4B^2-t^2\right)+C$ , I think $a^2-b^2\ne b^2-a^2$, so where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since $f$ is a parabola, the equation is fulfilled iff $2B$ is the first coordinate of the extremum of $f$.  But at on the other hand, its first coordinate $B/A$.  So show that $A=1/2$.

Edit: for any parabola given by $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ it is well known that the first coordinate of its vertex is $x_v=-b/2a$.  It is easily proved that $g$ is symmetric to $x=-b/2a$, i. e., $g(x_v-t)=g(x_v+t)$. In our case we achieve $x_v=-b/2a=-(-2B)/2A=B/A$.  OTOH $x_v$ should equal $2B$, which is fulfilled when $A=1/2$, which it is indeed.  Here the values of $B$ and $C$ don't matter.

Comment: Hmm, intresting, but how did you realize that the equation is fulfilled iff $2B$ is the first coordinate of the extremum of $f$ ?

Comment: @AndreiMihai The equation claims that $f$ is symmetric about $x=2B$: the values of first coordinates that differ by $t$ from $2B$ are equal.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand we have $\:f\left(t\right)=At^2-2Bt+C=2Bt-At^2+C=\frac{1}{2}t\left(4B-t\right)+C$, after replace we obtain what we want, but the reason for which have $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2}t\left(4B-T\right)+C$ and not $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2}t\left(t-4B\right)+C$, is because **2B** is the first coordinate of the extremum of our function, I've right?